Trouble with AMD RX5500M Graphics Driver on Ubuntu 20.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and encountered an issue when attempting to connect a second monitor via HDMI. The monitor works perfectly under Windows 11, suggesting that the problem lies with my Ubuntu setup. I noticed that Ubuntu is utilizing "llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6, 256 bits)" instead of the AMD RX5500M graphics card.
After checking AMD's official website, I couldn't find a Linux driver for the RX5500M
here. I'm still searching for a workaround to properly use my graphics card with Ubuntu. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

In the linux world, drivers aren't usually installed directly from manufacturers, but rather via distributions.  Is firmware-linux-nonfree, firmware-amd-graphics, and xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu installed?  you might also need mesa-vulkan-drivers
